# passing user data with Python-Flask and mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, flask

So basically I have an "/add" route where it is used to manually seed in test user data to mongodb and I want to be able to pass that user's ID to the URL for the route "/agreement" so when the user is on the agreement page, their `"_id"` will be mapped to that URI and the info they enter on the agreement page will update their data that we seeded in the "/add" route.

```
@app.route('/add')
def add():
    users = mongo.db.users
    users.insert({
        "_id" : "autogenID",
        "_comment" : " File structure for files in client collection",
        "client_name" : "Name_of_firm",
        "contact_name" : "Name_of_contact",
        "contact_email" : "Email_ID_of_contact",
        "contact_password" : "passowrd_encryped_bcrypt",
        "client_industry" : "client_industry",
        "monthly_checks_processed": "monthly_checks_processed",
        "parent_id" : "client_id",
        "child_id" : [{
            "child_id": "client_id", 
            "child_id": "client_id"
        }],
        "agreement_authorised" : "boolean_yes_no",
        "agreement" : "agreement_text",
        "client_card" : [{
            "name_on_card": "client_name",
            "credit_card_number": "credit_card_number_bycrypt",
            "expiration_date" : "expiration_date_bycrypt",
            "credit_card_cvc" : "credit_card_cvc_bycrypt",
            "active" : "boolean_yes_no"
        }]
    })
    all_users = users.find()
    for user in all_users:
        print user


@app.route('/agreement', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def agreenment(id):
    user = mongo.db.users.find("_id")
    print user
    return render_template('agreement.html', user=user)
```

I think the issue lies in the agreement resource where maybe I should write `/agreement/<id>` but I think I am missing a fundamental understanding of where the `<id>` is instantiated.  I also don't completely understand what the function of the agreement parameter is but I put `(id)` because this seems like something I would have to do in order to get the user's info passed to another resource.

I also think `user = mongo.db.users.find("_id")` might not be correct as well as `return render_template('agreement.html', user=user)`.  Part of me thinks that maybe I should do redirect instead of render but if anyone can lend a hand I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You should avoid using `id` as an identifier because you end up shadowing the [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@app.route('/agreement/<user_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def agreement(user_id):
    user = mongo.db.users.find_one({"_id": user_id})
    print user
    return render_template('agreement.html', user=user)
```

URL parameter names in Flask are specified in the `route` parameter, and they have to match the decorated function's signature.

Querying in Mongo is done by passing a dict specifying the constraints, so `db.users.find_one({"_id": user_id})` will return a single result with _id matching the user_id variable.

Edit: Actually, as per [the documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one), you can just do:
`db.users.find_one(user_id)`.